# determing file object size before using file object

Tags: python, filesize, file-copying

I am attempting to determine the size of a downloaded file in python before parsing and manipulating it with BeautifulSoup. (I intend to update to ElementTree soon, but having briefly played with it, it does not solve the problem I am posing here, as far as I can see).

```
import urllib2, BeautifulSoup
query = 'http://myexample.file.com/file.xml'
f = urllib2.urlopen(query)
print len(f.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(f.read())
```

This code falters because when I `read()` the file the first time in `len()`, it naturally reaches an EOF and so the file object is then empty by the time I want to access it with BeautifulSoup.

My inital thought was simply to copy the object with a `fcopy = f` line, but this led me to learn I'm merely referencing the underlying object and gain nothing.

I then thought that `fcopy = copy.copy(f)` would create a true copy of the object, but apparently not as reading f still results in fcopy being an empty file object.

I even read about passing objects as parameters to functions in order to get round this, and tried the following code

```
import urllib2, BeautifulSoup
def get_bytes(file):
    return len(file.read())

query = 'http://myexample.file.com/file.xml'
f = urllib2.urlopen(query)
print(get_bytes(f))
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(f.read())
```

But I had the same problem. How can I determine the file size of this object without effectively destroying the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the content of the file into a variable and work with it:

```
import urllib2, BeautifulSoup

query = 'http://myexample.file.com/file.xml'
f = urllib2.urlopen(query)
content = f.read()
print len(content)
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(content)
```

Comment: doh! So flippin obvious! Thanks :)